# HTML Table to JSON file via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, json

Is there any possibility to convert an HTML table to JSON with PHP?

I have this JavaScript:

```
    <script>
(function() {
    var jsonArr = [];
    var obj = {};
    var rowIx = 0;
    var jsonObj = {};
    var thNum = document.getElementsByTagName('th').length;
    var arrLength = document.getElementsByTagName('td').length;

    for(i = 0; i < arrLength; i++){
        if(i%thNum === 0){
            obj = {};
        }
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('th')[i%thNum].innerHTML;
        var content = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[i].innerHTML;
        obj[head] = content;
        if(i%thNum === 0){
            jsonObj[++rowIx] = obj
        }   
    }           

    var result = "<br>"+JSON.stringify({"Values": jsonObj});
    document.write(result);
})();
</script>
```

which uses the below HTML code:

```
<TABLE border="3" rules="all" bgcolor="#E7E7E7" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
<TR>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">Date</font></TH>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial"><B>Teacher</B></font></TH>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">?</font></TH>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">Hour</font></TH>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">Subject</font></TH>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">Class</font></TH>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">Room</font></TH>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">(Teacher)</font></TH>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">(Room)</font></TH>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">XYY</font></TH>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial"><B>Information</B></font></TH>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">(Le.) nach</font></TH>
</TR>
<TR><TD align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">24.9.</font></TD>
<TD align=center><font size="3" face="Arial"><B><strike>Dohe</strike></B></font></TD>
<TD align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">Free</font></TD>
<TD align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">1</font></TD>
<TD align=center><font size="3" face="Arial"><strike>Math</strike></font> </TD>
<TD align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">(9)</font> </TD>
<TD align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">---</font> </TD>
<TD align=center><font size="3" face="Arial"><strike>Dohe</strike></font></TD>
<TD align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">A001</font></TD>
<TD align=center>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD align=center>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">Free.</font></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

to generate this JSON code:

```
{"Values":{"1":{"Date":"24.9.","Teacher":"Dohe","?":"Free","Hour":"1","Subject":"Math ","Class":"(9) ","Room":"--- ","(Teacher)":"Dohe","(Room)":"A001","XYY":" ","Information":" ","(Le.) nach":"Free."},"2":{"Date":"26.9.","Teacher":"John","?":"Free","Hour":"8","Subject":"Bio ","Class":"(9) ","Room":"--- ","(Teacher)":"John","(Room)":"A021","XYY":" ","Information":" ","(Le.) nach":"Free."}}}
```

The script is perfect but I need a script, which saves the JSON data to a file on the server automatically, without any user interaction.

Comment: Can post it to a PHP page via AJAX and just have the PHP page write it to a file.

Comment: and how ? Do you have a link or something ?

Comment: That depends, what have you tried? Want to use JQuery or raw JavaScript? When the PHP gets the data, do you want it to write it to a txt file or a json file. What do you want the name of the file to be? Are you sending an email after it's created? Storing a link in a database? Need more info about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I want that a program is loading a html Page. This page should automatically put the data from the table to a JSON called subs.json. That all nothing else should happen. But the user shouldn't do any action to make this happen, only load the page.

Comment: How is the HTML page generated, if it's dynamic, why not have the same data pushed to the file at the same time? If it's static, you have to rely on JavaScript. If the browser does not support JS, is that okay? IF 2 people load the page at the same time, do you want two files generated or should the second overwrite the first? Amend to the first? Still need more info.

Comment: The HTML file is daily generated by an program. This creates every day a new File. In this program is a template.html where you can add optional code. Here I added the java script. This file is then uploaded to a server by the user. In the next step the user should press a button in a windows programs which loads up the page in a web view.  If there are 2 request at the same time it should overwrite it.

Comment: I have some ideas on this, but it will take me a bit to write up. Will post an answer later tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say your JS logic is perfect, here is a PHP (ver 5.3+) conversion that uses DOM like your code.

This function loads a html file (you may use curl if it is an url) then convert it and save to a file.

```
function save_table_to_json ( $in_file, $out_file ) {
    $html = file_get_contents( $in_file );
    file_put_contents( $out_file, convert_table_to_json( $html ) );
}

function convert_table_to_json ( $html ) {
    $document = new DOMDocument();
    $document->loadHTML( $html );

    $obj = [];
    $jsonObj = [];
    $th = $document->getElementsByTagName('th');
    $td = $document->getElementsByTagName('td');
    $thNum = $th->length;
    $arrLength = $td->length;
    $rowIx = 0;

    for ( $i = 0 ; $i < $arrLength ; $i++){
        $head = $th->item( $i%$thNum )->textContent;
        $content = $td->item( $i )->textContent;
        $obj[ $head ] = $content;
        if( ($i+1) % $thNum === 0){ // New row. Slightly modified to keep it correct.
            $jsonObj[++$rowIx] = $obj;
            $obj = [];
        }
    }

    return json_encode([ "Values" => $jsonObj ]);
}

// Example
save_table_to_json( 'table.html', 'data.json' );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This gives me this: `{"Values":[{"Datum":"23.10.","Vertreter":"KUL","Art":"Vertretung","Stunde":"9","Fach":"O5","Klasse(n)":"5Z","Raum":"C111","(Lehrer)":"GAT","(Raum)":"C310","Vertr. von":"\u00a0","Vertretungs-Text":"\u00a0","(Le.) nach":"Klassenfahrt 10 A"},{"Datum":"2.` So it puts the data in an array. But what I need is this: `{ "Values": { "1": { "Head":"data", "Head2":"Data2"},"2"{` also with the id, which should be generated automatically. Could you help me ?

Comment: @MariusSchönefeld Very observant.  It is true, there are languages where it matters.  I have re-added the rowIx variable which should get you the result you need :)

Comment: Hey, I have a Problem with the Script now it says in the console Unexpected token `>` at this line `$document->loadHTML( $html );`

Comment: @MariusSchönefeld Check the HTML that all > and & are properly escaped. Many people write non-conformance HTML (v4) and rely on browsers to interpret the actual intention.  (And v5 got feed up with the inconsistencies and define these interpretations.)

Comment: Thanks for the anwser here is my HTML. I dont See a Problem. http://pastebin.com/CSg4Qi7T

Comment: @MariusSchönefeld I can load the file (PHP 5.6.14) and get the script element. Anyway, how about wrapping the script in html commnet? http://pastebin.com/gQfwWxV0

Comment: Still this error when I load the Page. SyntaxError: expected expression, got '>'

Comment: Perhaps you can open a new question with reproducible code? I can run this in phpfiddle: `<?php $html = file_get_contents("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=gQfwWxV0"); $document = new DOMDocument(); $document->loadHTML( $html ); var_export( $document->getElementsByTagName( 'script' )->item( 0 ) ); ?>`

Comment: Hey again me, now I have a new question which is based on this code. Could you help me ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745667/convert-a-selected-html-table-to-json

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like using JQuery, yet if you don't know or can't insert it as a SRC, then we should assume to use JavaScript. So we will post the JSON data to our PHP via AJAX when the page is done loading. The PHP will then write this JSON into a new file on the server called `subs.json` and will be overwritten each time the script runs.

We will start with the JavaScript:

```
<script>
function collectData() {
    var jsonArr = [];
    var obj = {};
    var rowIx = 0;
    var jsonObj = {};
    var thNum = document.getElementsByTagName('th').length;
    var arrLength = document.getElementsByTagName('td').length;

    for(i = 0; i < arrLength; i++){
        if(i%thNum === 0){
            obj = {};
        }
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('th')[i%thNum].innerHTML;
        var content = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[i].innerHTML;
        obj[head] = content;
        if(i%thNum === 0){
            jsonObj[++rowIx] = obj;
        }   
    }           
    return jsonObj;
}

function postJSONData(json){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "/subPost.php");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var return_data = xmlhttp.responseText;
            alert(return_data);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send("values="+JSON.stringify(json));
}

postJSONData(collectData());
</script>
```

At this point, the page should post your JSON to a PHP page called `subPost.php` located at the same level as the page that is executing this JS. This PHP Will look like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['values'])){
        $values = $_POST['values'];
        $fp = fopen('subs.json', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $values);
        fclose($fp);
        echo "Values written to subs.json.\r\n";
} else {
        echo "No Post data received.";
}
?>
```

I made a working example you can see here: http://www.yrmailfrom.me/projects/testPost/ and the content of http://www.yrmailfrom.me/projects/testPost/subs.json is:

`{"1":{"<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"3\">Date</font>":"<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"3\">24.9.</font>","<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"3\"><b>Teacher</b></font>":"<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"3\"><b><strike>Dohe</strike></b></font>","<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"3\">?</font>":"<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"3\">Free</font>","<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"3\">Hour</font>":"<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"3\">1</font>","<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"3\">Subject</font>":"<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"3\"><strike>Math</strike></font> ","<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"3\">Class</font>":"<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"3\">(9)</font> ","<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"3\">Room</font>":"<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"3\">---</font> ","<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"3\">(Teacher)</font>":"<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"3\"><strike>Dohe</strike></font>","<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"3\">(Room)</font>":"<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"3\">A001</font>","<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"3\">XYY</font>":"`

This is not valid JSON. It seems that some data is being misunderstood. I suspect that this is due to characters in the values, like `&nbsp;`. I see this in the posted data:

```
"<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"3\">XYY</font>":"
    [nbsp;","<font_face] => \"Arial\" size=\"3\">(Le.) nach</font>":"<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"3\"
>Free.</font>"}}
```

I was able to overcome this with another small JS function:

```
function nbsp2space(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
}
```

Then use this function in `collectData()` like so:

`obj[head] = nbsp2space(content);`

Now when the page executes, we post the data to the PHP and it's written to the file subs.json.

Comment: thank you for the Code !!!!! I integrated it on my server but its still the incorrect JSON format.

Comment: What are you seeing in your `subs.json`? Also making use of FireBug in FireFox, what are you posting exactly?

Comment: In the sub.json it says `{"1":{"<font size=\"3\" face=\"Arial\">Date</font>":"<font size=\"3\" face=\"Arial\">24.9.</font>",...` and this is exactly what i am posting

Comment: The script takes everything what is between `<TH align=center>` and `</TH>`, which means also the `<font size="3" face="Arial"> </font>` or `<strike> </strike>` this must excluded but how ?

Comment: If i add the line  `document.write("<br>"+JSON.stringify({"Values": jsonObj}));  ` to the script it prints the completely right result. It also gives the ID number 1 ,2 ,3 etc.. So the error must be in the AJAX part but i don't know AJAX

Comment: If i replace ` JSON.stringify(json);` with `JSON.stringify({name:"John Rambo", time:"2pm"})` I get `{name:"John Rambo", time:"2pm"}` in subs.son

Comment: What do you get if you use `{name: "&nbsp;", time: "0000"}`?

Comment: `{"name":"` only this nothing more

Comment: That means that when stringify is running, it's converting `&` to `[`, and you need to catch that before hand. Please pastebin your current code.

Comment: When you uncomment the alert in line 82, what is shown?

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing like this:

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>No</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>Test</td>
<td>test@example.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>Test 2</td>
<td>test2@example.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>Test 3</td>
<td>test3@example.com</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
          data = new Array();
          columns = [];
          var row = new Array();
          $('table tr').each(function(index,tr){
              var index = index;
              if(index == 0){ // First we get column names from th.

                $(tr).find('th').each(function(thIndex,thValue){
                  columns.push($(thValue).text());
                });
              } else {
                $(tr).find('td').each(function(tdIndex,tdValue){
                  row[tdIndex] = $(tdValue).text(); // Put each td value in row
                });

                data.push(row); // now push each row in data.
                row = new Array(); // reset row after push
              }

          });
        // Send it to PHP for further work:
          $.post('json.php', { data: data, columns: columns }, function(response){
          // TODO with response
          });
        })
        </script>
```

**json.php**

```
$data = $_POST['data']; // Each rows values
$columns = $_POST['columns']; // Columns names

for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {

  $json[] = array(($i+1) => array_combine($columns, $data[$i]));

}

$json = json_encode($json);
// TODO with $json eg: file_put_contents();
```

the output you will get after `json_encode()` is:

```
{"values":[{"1":{"No":"1","Name":"Test","Email":"test@example.com"}},{"2":{"No":"2","Name":"Test 2","Email":"test2@example.com"}},{"3":{"No":"3","Name":"Test 3","Email":"test3@example.com"}}]}
```

**Note** [jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js) must be included before running this.

Comment: Thank you for the code. The output should be `{ "values" : { "1": {"Name":"Test","Email":"test@example.com"}, { "2" : { "Name":"Test 2","Email":"test2@example.com"}`

Comment: then you can simply do: `$json = json_encode(array('values' => $json));
echo $json;`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1ufPXPKn and http://pastebin.com/DJvk9wiu this is my code but it doesn't works

Comment: any error in console ? i've tested it and it's working

Comment: yes `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery
(anonyme Funktion)test1.html:24`

Comment: you should add jQuery in top of you head tag: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91830/discussion-between-touqeer-shafi-and-marius-schonefeld).

Comment: i solved everything except one problem
the syntax is still wrong
ist should be `{"Values": { "1": {"hello":"test"}, {"test":"hello"}}}`
but it is `{"Values": { "1": {"hello":"test"}}, {"test":"hello"}}}` How can that be fixed ?